# Removing unnecessary space

Tags: spacing

I would like to ask about this specifical spacing problem:

[image]

Is there a way that I can remove that unnecessary blank space? Not all of it, but at least a good proportion of it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{How to remove the space  from above this}
\author{ABC}
\date{11 July 2018}

\begin{document}

\maketitle


    Calculate: $$\int_0^{\infty} \sqrt{x}e^{-x^2}\sin^3{(x^2)}dx$$
$$\int_0^1$$
\end{document}
```

As an aditional question, how can I align the integrals that they will look the same but they will be underneath the word "Calculate"?

Comment: You're using the wrong tool here. Look for something like a `theorem` environment etc. or `amsmath` `align` environment.  `$$...$$` is outdated syntax.

Comment: to echo the comment by @ChristianHupfer, the use of two independent display lines leaves you open to the possibility that a page break could occur between them. (although not in such a short piece as this)  also, the spacing between these lines isn't optimal.  please do take a look at the amsmath documentation -- `texdoc amsldoc`.

Comment: What do you mean with unnecessary blank space?

Comment: you should not use `$$` anyway but certainly you do not want them here as they produces a centred display and you are asking for the math not to be centred but placed to the left under `Calculate`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know if I understood properly what you're asking, still giving it a try ;).

Are you looking for something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Calculate:
\begin{flalign*}
    &\int_0^{\infty} \sqrt{x}e^{-x^2}\sin^3{(x^2)}dx && \\
    &\int_0^1 &&
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

That compiles to:

[image]

To shift the title upwards insert this in the preamble

```
\usepackage{titling}
\setlength{\droptitle}{-40ex}
```

and tweak the parameter `-40ex` to shift it upwards or downwards. With this value, it should roughly be at the top margin of the page.